# Can the Wealth system from d20 Modern be adapted to 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, conversion, d20-modern, wealth

D20 Modern had a system where instead of tracking your money directly, it would track a "wealth" attribute. Transactions have a DC instead of price, and a Wealth check is made to determine if a character can afford buying something. The check can also alter Wealth representing excessive spending or profits.

Has anyone published something like this for D&D 5e? Or has anyone had success adapting it as a homebrew system?

Comment: I edited your question so the title better reflects the question, and to make it fit better within the SE guidelines. Certainly one could *attempt* to adapt it, or speculate how one could, but good answers on this site require experience having actually done so or seen it done. That said, if you feel I've failed to reflect the spirit of your question, please feel free to revert or further clarify what you're looking for.

Answer (score 9):

### 5e doesn't have that natively. But you've got two options...

1. The DMG gives good guidance on how to **design it yourself.** Check the DMG at pp.264-266: "New Ability Scores: Honor and Sanity."

   It's a description of those two particular scores, but has enough commentary to use them as a good structure for designing your own score. (And remember, that's the purpose of the core rules: to give you an excellent example of a D&D game, so that you can craft *yours*.)
2. **Published Wealth rules:** On DM's guild you'll find [5-minute workday's variant rules](http://www.dmsguild.com/product/177820/5MWD-Presents-Variant-Rules). One of the variant rules presented is wealth, and it's explicitly modeled on the d20 modern system. Starting wealth, tie-in to 5e lifestyles, maintaining wealth, wealth checks, wealth saves (!), and business ownership: it's all there.

   I will admit: I've not (yet) played with this variant. I've used others from this author and been generally pleased. And at $0.50, it's not too much to try out.

If I can throw a piece of advice out there: if you decide ot go option 2, spend ten minutes to make up your own first. In my experience you'll learn a lot more about how you want *your* game to work by comparing yours to 5MWD's--no matter which or what you nd up using--than if you just read someone else's work.